# Set attribute value if correct type

Tags: postgresql

So I have a case where I need to set the value of an attribute depending on the type. To visualize a little bit, I have this table (lets call the table '`forecasts`'):

```
| creation_time | id |    d_type    |    d_amount  |
|---------------|--- |--------------|--------------|
|    1534842000 |  1 |           2  |          1.3 |
|    1534842000 |  2 |           3  |          0.3 |
```

The `d_type` means which type it is, so for example, let's say:

```
1 = nothing
2 = rain
3 = snow
```

How could I get a table that looks something like:

```
| creation_time | id |    rain      |    snow      |
|---------------|--- |--------------|--------------|
|    1534842000 |  1 |          1.3 |            0 |
|    1534842000 |  2 |            0 |          0.3 |
```

That is, the attribute should have a the value of `d_amount` if the attribute corresponds to the right `d_type`.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
        creation_time,
        id,
        "rain", CASE d_type WHEN 2 THEN d_amount END,
        "snow", CASE d_type WHEN 3 THEN d_amount END,
FROM forecasts;
```

But it returns a case-column that I don't want. I'm new to PostgreSQL so sorry for noobing this down. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
    creation_time,
    id,
    CASE d_type WHEN 2 THEN d_amount END as "rain",
    CASE d_type WHEN 3 THEN d_amount END as "snow",
  FROM forecasts;
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple! Although, the values are null if the the d_type doesn't match. I need them to be 0, but maybe I could add one more case somehow

Comment: Yeah, just needed to add "ELSE 0"

Comment: Or add  "ELSE null"